# A culture shock for me, what is in this alcohol?

Tags: culture

I bought some Chilean red wine on Taobao. Very nice! The company sent me a little, flat bottle of something containing 35% alcohol as a free gift.

On the label of the bottle it says:

至宝
特质三鞭酒

Among the ingredients are:

海狗鞭、鹿鞭、广狗鞭

有没有可能这瓶酒里面真的有这些鞭？？

Answer (score 2):

if you have culture shock, you must be, well, . . . non-chinese

the traditional folk “wisdom” is “以形補形” (roughly; eating particular animal’s organ to enhance one’s relevant organ)

> 有没有可能这瓶酒里面真的有这些鞭

do you fancy to have?  no lah. most likely, three of these, and other medicinal ingredients in thousands / millions of gallons of alcohol. then, a few hundred ml “distilled” into your bottle.

here’s a link of it’s tv commercial in 1980s, in english:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NGZ4dbGNSM

have fun :)

Comment: Haha! Thanks for the link! My 鞭 OK， I will look for something containing 大脑!

Comment: "...something containing 大脑!" --- 大小不重要 :)